# AutoMapper and mapping property from entity framework dbcontext

Tags: automapper

I am a bit new to AutoMapper, I am trying to map a property where the values from from an ef db context.

How would I go about doing that?

```cs
CreateMap<User, UserDto>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.Username, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Username))
.ForMember(dest => dest.NetworkId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.NetworkId))
.ForMember(dest => dest.Network, /*NEED TO TAKE NetworkId and PERFORM A lookup in DbContext AND SET Network property*/);
```

Comment: It looks like you are mapping from a user/view model to a data layer model (i.e. in order to save a users' changes). If this is the case, then it should not be necessary to map the navigation property. The Id alone should suffice.

Comment: EF will either already have the Network object loaded (using eager loading) or will load it when AutoMapper tries to map to the UserDto object (using lazy-loading).  You shouldn't have to do anything special.